# Trying to get a property of a non-object in 'mymodule_node_access()'

Tags: nodes

In a custom module, I try to make this code work :

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  if ($node->type = 'devis' and $op = 'view') {
    $field_language = field_language('node', $node, 'field_project');
    $project_node = node_load($node->fields->field_project[$field_language][0]['value']);
    if ($project_node->uid == $account->uid) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
    }   
    else {
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENIED;
    }
  } 
}
```

I get the following notice:

> Trying to get a property of a non-object in `mymodule_node_access()`

I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$node` in `hook_node_access()` can be either a string for the content-type or a node object.
I had to test if it was a string or an object.

```
if (is_string($node)) { 
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fields are directly on the node object, you're currently trying to find them in another object called `fields`.

Change this:

```
$project_node = node_load($node->fields->field_project[$field_language][0]['value']);
```

To this:

```
$project_node = node_load($node->field_project[$field_language][0]['value']);
```

And it should work.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was also going to add that all fields are attached to a [Drupal node object](https://www.drupal.org/node/49768) directly as the property `field_{field_name}`.

Comment: Thank ou for your fast answer, I changed it and still have the same notice, I really don't know what is the matter